# What is the best icon to communicate the "Show Details" link?

Tags: usability, icons, collapsible-panels

What would you use as icon to expand a box including some details (i.e. regarding a product specification)? Would you use the same icon to expand details about a single datum in an array of data (such as a  data table)?

Answer (score 2):

I would use an arrow but would also put a text label to clarify the button:

[image]

Another option are the three dots, also commonly used to indicate 'more'.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I usually put a text label on every icon. So would you comunicate the interaction instead of the semantic meaning of the content?